# Inequalities with random variables, prove that $P(X>x) \leq e^{-tx+t^2\sigma^2}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have this exercise but I'm a little confused about how to solve this.

Suppose that $P(|X|\leq b)=1$ for all $b>0$, such that $E X =0$, $Var(X)=\sigma^2$. Then for $0<t<b^{-1}$ and $x>0$

$$
P(X>x) \leq e^{-tx+t^2\sigma^2}
$$

And

$$
P(|X|>x) \leq 2e^{-tx+t^2\sigma^2}
$$

Any idea or suggestion?

Comment: Take a look on Chernoff Bounds